# Python figure with the entire set of labels

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a figure to visualize the entire covariance matrix.
 However, I am not able to include the entire list of labels. See the working example below:

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm as cm

numberYears=len(range(2002,2018+1))
covMatrix=np.ones([numberYears,numberYears])
for count1,year1 in enumerate(range(2002,2018+1))    :
    for count2,year2 in enumerate(range(2002,2018+1))    :        
        covMatrix[count1,count2]=1-(abs(count1-count2)/numberYears)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
cmap = cm.get_cmap('rainbow', 30)
cax = ax1.imshow(covMatrix, interpolation="nearest", cmap=cmap)
labels=[]
for year in range(2002,2018+1):
    labels.append(str(year))

ax1.set_xticklabels(labels,fontsize=10,rotation=90)
ax1.set_yticklabels(labels,fontsize=10)   
fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1.0])
fig.savefig('map.png')
```

[image: Representation of the covariance matrix]

Note that my labels are [2002,2003,...,2017,2018] and the entire list is not included as a label of the figure. How can I deal with this?

Comment: One of my most repeated comment below matplotlib questions: *Never* set the ticklabels without setting the tick locations as well. I.e. do not use `set_xticklabels` without first setting the locations via `set_xticks`. Of course alternatively use any of matplotlibs locators and formatters.

Answer (score 0):

Considering @ImportanceOfBeingErnest comment, I was able to find the solution. I include the argument "extent" in the function "imshow" and I also "set.xticks":

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm as cm

numberYears=len(range(2002,2018+1))
covMatrix=np.ones([numberYears,numberYears])
for count1,year1 in enumerate(range(2002,2018+1))    :
    for count2,year2 in enumerate(range(2002,2018+1))    :        
        covMatrix[count1,count2]=1-(abs(count1-count2)/numberYears)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
cmap = cm.get_cmap('rainbow', 30)
cax = ax1.imshow(covMatrix, interpolation="nearest", cmap=cmap,extent=[2002,2018,2002,2018])
labels=[]
for year in range(2002,2018+1):
    labels.append(str(year))
ax1.set_xticks(listYears)
ax1.set_yticks(listYears)    

ax1.set_xticklabels(labels,fontsize=10,rotation=90)
ax1.set_yticklabels(labels,fontsize=10)   
fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,1.0])
fig.savefig('mapTeste.png')
```